# Fading popup dialog with css (not jquery)

Tags: html, css, popup, fade, transition

I have a very simple pop up image using CSS. I would like to know if there's a way to fade it. All my efforts with transitions -o-transition; -ms-transition, -moz-transition; -webkit-transition; transition,; bla, bla, bla ... didn't make anything.

thanks

```css
#button {
  position: relative;
  margin: 1px 0 0 0;
  padding-top: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display:inline-block;
  position:absolute;
  list-style:none;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-size:cover;
}

.popup {
  position: absolute;
  padding-top:30px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: none;
  text-align:center;
  background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  z-index: 101;
}

.popup:target {
  display: block;
}

.popup img {
  padding: 10px;
  z-index: 120;
  border: solid 1px gray;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color:#FFFFFF;
  -moz-border-radius: 2px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
  border-radius: 2px;
}
```

```html
 <div>
   <!-- button -->
   <div id="button">
     <a href="#bigger" title="LALA"><img src="http://imagenes.es.sftcdn.net/es/scrn/115000/115177/thumbnail_1459842713-100x100.png" title="Landscape button" alt="landscape"></a>
   </div>

   <!--pop up-->
   <div id="bigger" class="popup">
     <a href="#"><img src="http://www.robertofarrenphotography.com/wp-content/uploads/galleries/post-1336/thumbnails/BOSTON%20LANDSCAPE%20PHOTOGRAPHER_USA_049.jpg" alt="landscape"/></a>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: jQuery has fading effects, have you tried using those?

Comment: I didn't, i'll look on google to see what i find. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

follow this example code for your problem
(you  can remove header and footer for modal dialog if you dont want it)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
/* Add animation (Chrome, Safari, Opera) */
@-webkit-keyframes example {
from {top:-100px;opacity: 0;}
to {top:0px;opacity:1;}
}

/* Add animation (Standard syntax) */
@keyframes example {
from {top:-100px;opacity: 0;}
to {top:0px;opacity:1;}
}

/* The modal's background */
.modal {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

/* Display the modal when targeted */
.modal:target {
  display: table;
  position: absolute;
}

/* The modal box */
.modal-dialog {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

/* The modal's content */
.modal-dialog .modal-content {
  margin: auto;
  background-color: #f3f3f3;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
  outline: 0;
  border: 1px #777 solid;
  text-align: justify;
  width: 80%;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);

  /* Add animation */
  -webkit-animation-name: example; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.5s; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  animation-name: example;
  animation-duration: 0.5s;
}

/* The button used to close the modal */
.closebtn {
  text-decoration: none;
  float: right;
  font-size: 35px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #fff;
}

.closebtn:hover,
.closebtn:focus {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.container {
  padding: 2px 16px;
}

header {
  background-color: #5cb85c;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: white;
}

footer {
  background-color: #5cb85c;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: white;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<a href="#id01"><img src="http://imagenes.es.sftcdn.net/es/scrn/115000/115177/thumbnail_1459842713-100x100.png" title="Landscape button" alt="landscape"></a>

<div id="id01" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
<div class="modal-content">
  <header class="container">
    <a href="#" class="closebtn">×</a>
    <h2>Modal Header</h2>
  </header>
  <div class="container">
    <a href="#"><img src="http://www.robertofarrenphotography.com/wp-content/uploads/galleries/post-1336/thumbnails/BOSTON%20LANDSCAPE%20PHOTOGRAPHER_USA_049.jpg" alt="landscape" width="100%" height="100%"/></a>
  </div>
  <footer class="container">
    <p>Modal footer</p>
  </footer>
</div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ok, i could with the fadein, but not with the fadeout. Anyway, i'm happy with the result.

codepen:
http://codepen.io/danielillo/pen/JRoRzQ?editors=1100

Comment: i am glad you done it with my example code,if its help full then you can vote and tick my answer thanks (y)